# Swapping two bytes in perl

Tags: perl, byte, reverse, swap

I am trying to swap two bytes at a time in a file. So I was thinking I could read in two bytes at a time and use reverse to switch the bytes around. However I am not sure how to read two bytes at a time in perl. Can someone make a suggestion

Comment: you can use the [`read()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html) function to read 2 bytes at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading two bytes at a time is hugely inefficient. You should continue to read larger blocks at a time and process the bytes in the buffer.

```
$buf =~ s/(.)(.)/$2$1/sg;
```

or

```
$buf = pack 'S<*, unpack 'S>*', $buf;
```

Comment: would you suggest reading in the entire file at once?
E.G.

`open(TEST, "<", $filename) or die "cannot open";
binmode(TEST);
$/=undef; 
my buf = <TEST>;
close(INPUT);
$buf =~s/(.)(.)/$2$1/sg;`

Comment: Depends on the size of the file, but yeah, that would be my starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Use "read" (http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html) to read and pass "2" for the LENGTH parameter to read 2 bytes (by default) of data.

For performance reasons, if you have a large file, you might want to consider reading more (or perhaps all) of the file once, instead of calling read ((filesize in bytes)/2) times.